# Redirect old php link to wordpress link in .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect old page link to new wordpress link using .htaccess, I tried two following redirection steps but none of them works.

Both are in same domain like `www.example.com/folder/first-index.php?idTop=0` and `www.example.com/foldernew/products-list/`

```
Redirect 301 "/folder/first-index.php?idTop=0" "/foldernew/products-list/"
RedirectPermanent /folder/first-index.php?idTop=0 /foldernew/products-list/
```

I am trying other steps to but no luck. Please anyone correct my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It might helps you.

```
[code autolinks=”false”]
# 301 redirect for main pages
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Your_old_path/$ http://Your_new_path/
[/code]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/first-index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^idTop=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foldernew/products-list/ [R=301,L]
```